# Calling "this" from an external function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a validation script for a form and rather than setting up a separate validation function for every input that requires something to be entered, I would like to create a single function that will be fired on blur of any input in the form.

How can I associate jQuery's `this` selector from an external function? This is what I have tried:

```
function inputCheck() {
    if ($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass('error');
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
}

$('input').blur(function() {
    inputCheck();
});
```

Comment: `inputCheck( $(this) );` pass it to the function. `function inputCheck( el ) {`

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with jQuery.  You should pass a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and that's one, for me, of the best javascript strenght  easily via bind or call:

```
inputCheck.call(this);
```

`call` function takes as param a `this` object which a hash of functions/objects/vars (so you can pass `this` as well as other objects, `{foo: "bar"}` will make a this var with foo property initialized), and the next arguments are the args passed to the function

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could just pass a reference to the function directly:

```
$('input').blur(inputCheck);
```